# How can I play audio async using MediaElement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I believe what I'm looking to do is play audio asynchronously. I'm coding an app for Windows 8 which requires that an audio file is played EVERYTIME a button is pressed. The problem I'm running into is that, the file will play, but if it has not finished playing and you hit the button, it will not sound again.

```
XAML
<MediaElement x:Name="KickBasicAudio"
              Source="Assets/Drums/Dance/KickBasic.wav"
              AutoPlay="False" />
<Button Content="KICK" ClickMode="Press" Click="KickBasicPlay"/>

C#
private void KickBasicPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    KickBasicAudio.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `SoundPlayer` may be a better option in this case, as this allows Asyc playing

```
using System.Media; //The reference needed.

private SoundPlayer _player = new SoundPlayer("file");

private void KickBasicPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Was unaware of this, this would definitely be a better alternative to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a background worker thread to do it. Try this.

```
using System.ComponentModel; //This is the reference needed.

private void KickBasicPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker thread = new BackgroundWorker();
    thread.DoWork += (sender, e) => { KickBasicAudio.Play() };
}
```

Comment: Aren't BackgroundWorkers used in Javascript? I using C#/XAML.

Comment: Do I have to use a reference?

Comment: Even when I include the reference I still get the error: The type or namespace name 'BackgroundWorker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: private void KickBasicPlay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker thread = new BackgroundWorker();
            thread.DoWork += (sender, e) => { KickBasicAudio.Play() };
        }

Comment: I am unsure of your problem, are you sure that you put the using directive in correctly?

Comment: I think so, I added it to the list at the top of the file.

Comment: Try replacing BackgroundWorker with System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Comment: I have intellisense on, and Visual Studio is not showing BackgroundWorker, even when I type System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Comment: Perhaps try creating a separate thread for handling audio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx